# How To Enable Einstein Activity Capture In Sandbox Org

Tags: sandbox, einstein-activity-capture, lightning-sync-configurations

After successfully setting up Einstein Activity Capture (for Google) on my production org, I then created a sandbox for it.

[image]

In the sandbox org, when I go to Einstein Activity Capture in Settings, the message shows to "Turn off Lightning Sync"

[image]

I turned off GMail/Outlook integration and don't see any other option to turn off Lightning Sync. How do you enable Einstein Activity Capture in a sandbox org?

Thank you

Comment: if you go to `Setup --> Outlook Integration & Sync`, are you able to turn off lightning sync?

Comment: It says "Lightning Sync is no longer available for setup", same message as for Gmail.

Comment: You can try disabling through `EmailIntegrationSettings` in the Metadata API. You can retrieve (using workbench or VS code) with the package.xml identified [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_emailintegrationsettings.htm). I presume `enableContactAndEventSync` will be `true` on retrieve. Change that to `false` and deploy.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves you're correct, the `enableContactAndEventSync` was true. Einstein Activity Capture now works. Thank you. If you'd like to post your answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the UI isn't behaving, you can disable this through the Metadata API  with the [EmailIntegrationSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_emailintegrationsettings.htm) metadata type.

The field you're interested in is `enableContactAndEventSync`. This'll return `true` assuming Lightning sync is actually activated and preventing you from activating Einstein Activity Capture.

Within VS Code (or whichever deployment means you'd like), retrieve with the following package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>EmailIntegration</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <version>52.0</version>
</Package>
```

This'll create a `Settings` folder wtihin your project (if you've never pulled anything in before).

Change `enableContactAndEventSync` to `false` within the `EmailIntegrationSettings` file, re-deploy, and this should deactivate Lightning Sync. Thus, allowing you to go through the EAC setup within the UI.