# Unable to setup Einstein Activity Capture in my sandbox org

Tags: sandbox, salesforce-for-outlook, einstein-activity-capture, lightning-sync-configurations

I am trying to enable Einstein Activity Capture in Sandbox org to test it before making it available to all users in Production, however, some of its features are not enabled while setting it up as shown in the screenshots below:

On the first step, it does not allow me to choose Google G Suite and shows the message "You still have users syncing with Lightning Sync so some options can't be selected".

[image]

I selected Microsoft Office 365. Then on moving on to the next step, it only allows to select 'Org-level OAuth 2.0' method and the rest are disabled. Again, the same message about Lighting Sync being used is shown.

[image]

I checked and Lightning Sync is disabled in this org. I also checked through the metadata as suggested here: [How to Enable Einstein Activity Capture in Sandbox Org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/348788/how-to-enable-einstein-activity-capture-in-sandbox-org)

[image]
The "enableContactAndEventSync" attribute is set to False.
Can anyone suggest why this message is being shown and how to disable Lightning Sync completely so that I can access all the authentication methods Einstein Activity Capture has to offer? I specifically want to access the "User Level OAuth 2.0" option.

Answer (score 0):

As per the setting page instruction:

*Your Lightning Sync settings were moved to Einstein Activity Capture. Make sure all users in the configuration have the Einstein Activity Capture permission. Users without the permission are still using Lightning Sync.
When you’re done assigning the Einstein Activity Capture permission to users, you’re ready to turn off Lightning Sync. [More Info](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_sync_move_assign.htm)*

Also, you can check and turn off the lighting sync from these two settings to avail both of the options that are allowed to select.

- Gmail Integration and Sync
- Outlook Integration and Sync

Steps:

- In setup, quick find box, type "sync" and go to either **"Gmail Integration And Lightning Sync"** or **"Outlook Integration And Lightning Sync"**, from there disable the Lightning sync option.